# Pass http request header parameter in SAP Gateway

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-gateway

I created a oData in the SAP Gateway system and want to read odata from SAP gateway system with passing parameter in the HTTP header. 
In the UI debug view I can see my parameter in the "Request Headers"

[image]

But the custom parameter "_user" doesn't appear in the SAP gateway system side when I open the debugger view

[image]

Can you please give me some hints about this issue? I tried both sap odata model and jQuery to call odata service which is provided by SAP gateway system, but none of them have the custom parameter in the gateway system side. Thank you!

Comment: it was solved by declaring odata model in the manifest file rather than declaring it manually in controller class.

Comment: So post  your solution, please, so that others can see it